# Cannot resolve symbol '?attr/actionBarSize' after updating Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0 for buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-studio-3.0

After updating Android Studio from 2.3 to 3.0 I changed `buildToolsVersion` from 26.0.0 to 26.0.2 and after that I am getting this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol '?attr/actionBarSize
```

Xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Maybe you hava upgraded the version of gradle.

Comment: Trying clicking Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Nothing helped, but changing:

`?attr/actionBarSize` to `?android:attr/actionBarSize` did the job.

That's actually a bug in few versions. Even if you won't fix it, Android will automatically fix it at runtime.

Comment: I think `?android:attr/actionBarSize` is only compatible with api 21, `?attr/actionBarSize` requires a pre-21 sdk installed for Android Studio to see it. The other issue for me was making sure the compileSdk and support libs have the same major version number (27 in my case)

Comment: Hmmm, seems a little magical, but it works.  I'd love to see a definitive explanation that describes precisely what breaks with the various sdks and what works and why.

Comment: it seems like a bug because the project compile and build ok with this error.

Answer (score 34):

Update all your library versions to `26.1.0` (to the most recent version) and also add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

if you are using Android Studio 3.0.0 and above then use

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Sync your project and the error will automatically resolve because `?attr/actionBarSize` is part of `v4` library.

Comment: specify which library version you are talking about

Comment: I had to change :
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
to
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: Use `implementation` instead of `compile` now.

Comment: I think this answer should not be the selected answer. Because it forces you to use the support-v4 library when you don't have to. You can Sid and Victoria Klimova's answer is the best answer, you can avoid using unnecessary library in your project easily...

Comment: This answer didn't even help me. Sid's answer helps, but I don't understand why do I need `android:` prefix when I have already added `android` namespace `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` does anybody know?

Comment: This answer was true for older version of android studio but now it's not working for new version so I am accepting @VictoriaKlimova's answer as correct. Thanks EvrenYurtesen for pointing this.

Comment: I agree with @Suragch compile has is being replaced with implementation

Answer (score 28):

In the project directory hierarchy switch "Android" to "Project".
Then delete a folder ".idea/libraries", only "libraries".
Select an option from the menu  "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart".

Comment: This worked for me too. But curious, why it did. What exactly does "Invalidate Caches / Restart" do?

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me with `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1`

Answer (score 11):

Good day, I know this is a bit late.

but I have encountered this one too, when I updated to Android Studio 3.0

what i did is I changed

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Hope it can help somebody.

Comment: support_library = '27.1.1' to support_library = '27.1.0' worked for me. not sure why downgrading fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to fix exactly the same problem. 
1. Go to SDK manager. 
2. Check Android API 27 and Android 8.0 (Oreo)
3. Click "Apply" to download and install those SDKs
4. In build.gradle, change the 'buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"' to 'buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"' and do a gradle sync.

Hope this can help fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your buildToolsVersion version differs from version in dependencies 
(e.g. buildToolsVersion is 27.0.0 
but implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'). Make them the same.

Answer (score 2):

my problem solved by changing `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` from `26` to the last version `27`, also u need to upgrade ur `dependencies` to `27`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com......"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
}
```

hope this solve ur problem too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your build.gradle(app) dependencies:

```
resolutionStrategy {
    force libraries.support.appCompat
    force libraries.support.design
    force 'com.android.support:support-utils:26.0.1'
    force 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

I have updated the compile and support lib versions from 26.x.x to 27.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers here and so many others from lots of places but only the below techniques worked for me. 
The simple way is you just need to ***close*** the project then ***import*** the same project as a ***Gradle project*** 
Or you can go to Project structure -> project -> change Gradel plugin = 4.4 and Android plugin version = 3.1.4.
Both of these above methods work.

**Note:** These versions(4.4, 3.1.4) are latest when I write this answer please use the latest version instead of these.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, if you're using `AndroidX` add this :

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `R.attr.actionBarSize` to `androidx.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you hava upgraded the version of gradle.
when my gradle version is 4.4 and plugin version is 3.1.1.It is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this work:

delete all file in $HOME/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar

Answer (score 0):

Changed all [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) versions to the newest `27.1.1` and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

please replace android support libraries.

from

```
27.1.1
```

to

```
28.0.0-alpha3
```

and replace 27 to 28 for following cases:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 28
```

this will fix the issue.